# Command equivalent on restarting explorer.exe in Windows

Tags: restart

Is there command in Ubuntu that is equivalent on restarting explorer.exe in Windows?

Comment: What's your goal, basically ?

Answer (score 8):

If your goal is to restart file manager , then `pkill nautilus && nohup nautilus 2> /dev/null &`.

If you want to restart your desktop session, `sudo service lightdm restart`. This command kills everything, kicks you back to login screen. Effectively restarts your graphical session

Comment: But the latter kills all the app, right?

Comment: @tigerjack89 later kills everything, kicks you back to login screen. Effectivelly restarts your desktop session

Comment: yep, this is my point. I think you should add this to your answer because it is very different from killing explorer.exe in Windows.

Comment: @tigerjack89 I've already mentioned that it restarts desktop session in my answer, but I guess I can add that bitt,too

Comment: `sudo service lightdm restart` is probably equivalent to `ctrl + alt + backspace` in most distros

Comment: @Davide we're talking about Windows equivalent, tho

Comment: @Serg I know. I just thought it was worth mentioning it, as it's a standard way to restart X. However, I remember having to change something in ubuntu for it to work...